# How can I read and work with Binary values in the Registry using C#?

Tags: c#, registry

I'm trying to create a toggle function in C# for enabling and disabling the full view of the Windows Task Manager (because in recent versions they reduced the TM to a useless list of a few programs and no other data).

I found this:
https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/126960-reset-task-manager-default-windows-10-a.html

Which says to delete the following registry key:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TaskManager

This works to get TM to full view (regular mode), but if I have some psycho that wants it back in minified view, what do I do?

The key has the following two values:
[image]

When I manually toggle the value in the TM, the only value that changes is Preferences which is a binary value. I can see that it's changing, but I don't know what it's changing to or why. I can try to record the entire binary string and manually put that in my code (before and after), but that seems rather sloppy and prone to error because I have no idea what other data is stored there.

Is there a way to extract binary data to something useful - is it encoded in some way? I already have code to read values, change them, delete them etc, but how do I work with this?

Comment: Record the binaries and see what changes, I don't think there is documentation for that. Also found this https://superuser.com/questions/1629026/how-to-automate-setting-task-manager-from-its-default-simple-view-to-more-detail

Comment: That's challenging because there's no simple way I've found to export or print the values and I'd have to manually look through the whole thing. Once I've found it, how do I even change it? I don't know how to work with binary directly in this way. Also, what if it's a more complex data structure and I can't actually change it in that way without breaking something else?

Comment: Well, I guess the binary string would be pretty straightforward, just take a look at the link I sent and play with it. Save your registry settings so that if you mess with anything you can restore it. Have fun with it :)

Comment: Of course i looked at your link before responding. It's the same question, but does not have a workable answer. Additionally, I need to be able to determine the current state which means reading and working directly with the binary data (hence my question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so here's is what I did

I opened task manager (Ctrl+Shift+Escape in case you didn't know) and turned the view into "fewer details" and closed task manager.

I opened the registry that you have referenced in the question and once there from File I press Export and export the TaskManager entry as a txt file

Then I went back to the task manager and changed the view to "more details" and  closed the task manager once more. To make sure there is no problem with updating the registry, I closed regedit and opened the same location again and exported the entry to a txt file once more.

I compared the files using the Notepad++ compare plugin.

Between the two states of the registry entry there is only 1 bit of difference.
Here are the results:

this is for fewer details:

```
00000000   0d 00 00 00 60 00 00 00 - 60 00 00 00 04 02 00 00  ....`...`.......
00000010   d7 02 00 00 7f 03 00 00 - 4b 04 00 00 01 00 00 00  ×.......K.......
00000020   00 00 00 80 00 00 00 80 - d8 01 00 80 df 01 00 80  ........Ø...ß...
00000030   00 01 00 00 04 02 00 00 - d7 02 00 00 fa 06 00 00  ........×...ú...
00000040   d5 04 00 00 e8 03 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  Õ...è...........
...
```

And this is for more details:

```
00000000   0d 00 00 00 60 00 00 00 - 60 00 00 00 04 02 00 00  ....`...`.......
00000010   d7 02 00 00 7f 03 00 00 - 4b 04 00 00 00 00 00 00  ×.......K.......
00000020   00 00 00 80 00 00 00 80 - d8 01 00 80 df 01 00 80  ........Ø...ß...
00000030   00 01 00 00 04 02 00 00 - d7 02 00 00 fa 06 00 00  ........×...ú...
00000040   d5 04 00 00 e8 03 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  Õ...è...........
...
```

As you can see the only difference is that 01 becomes 00 in the second file. It is reasonable to assume that that bit toggles whether task manager is in full mode or minimized mode. I do not know how you will read it or write to it in c# per see (perhaps [this](https://codingvision.net/c-edit-registry-keys-or-values) might help). If you cannot do that as well just comment to this and I will try to help.

Also to confirm that it works, I opened task manager in more details mode, closed it, exported the registry to a reg file. The byte that we wanted to change was `0x00` at that time. I manually changed it to `0x01` in the registry file and imported the registry file. Indeed my task manager turned into fewer details mode. ,

As for the design considerations. Since you only wish to toggle a single preference, when toggling just read the entire value and change the necessary byte. If I counted correctly 29th byte is the byte you want to change but I would count it again myself. Make sure you only change the last bit of that value to 1 (or 0), in which case you can make sure that you are not altering anything else.

Edit 2:

I don't know why you are trying to make things harder or imagine that this process is somehow more complicated than it is. Oftentimes than not these things are pretty straightforward. Everything I have said in the previous edits and the original answer held out to be true.

I created two radio buttons one for minimize one for maximize in a Winforms application and just wrote their relative CheckChanged actions.

Here is the code:

```
private void MoreDetails(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    
    if (radioButton1.Checked)
    {
        #pragma warning disable CS8600 // Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.
        #pragma warning disable CS8602 // Dereference of a possibly null reference.
        RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TaskManager", true);
        byte[] data = (byte[])key.GetValue("Preferences");
        #pragma warning restore CS8602 // Dereference of a possibly null reference.
        #pragma warning restore CS8600 // Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.
        
        if (data != null)
        {
            data[28] &= (byte)0xFE;
            key.SetValue("Preferences", data);
            MessageBox.Show("Set to maximized view");
        }

        key.Close();
    }
}

private void FewerDetails(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (radioButton2.Checked)
    {
        #pragma warning disable CS8600 // Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.
        #pragma warning disable CS8602 // Dereference of a possibly null reference.
        RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TaskManager", true);
        byte[] data = (byte[])key.GetValue("Preferences");
        #pragma warning restore CS8602 // Dereference of a possibly null reference.
        #pragma warning restore CS8600 // Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.
        
        if (data != null)
        {
            data[28] |= (byte)0x01;
            key.SetValue("Preferences", data);
            MessageBox.Show("Set to minimized view");
        }

        key.Close();
    }
}
```

I have tried this code and it objectively works, atleast on my system which is a windows 10, every single time.

Comment: I did the same as you already and there were three bits of difference repeated several times. When I exported later, the bits that changed were different. It doesn't seem as simple as changing a single bit.

Comment: @not_a_generic_user well it makes sense that changing a single bit is enough, and as I said already, changing that manually seems to toggle the task manager view anyways. Maybe you have accidentally changed something else? Well either way I will try writing it in c# and let you know if it works.

Comment: @not_a_generic_user please check the edit.

Comment: I'm not one to argue with something that works so I gave it a try hoping it would. Unfortunately it did not. Note that I'm using Windows 11 and that might be why.

Comment: Nope, I was wrong. I re-ran the export test and noticed that the same bit changed as you said. It seems the value needs to be 0 for normal and 1 for the stupid minimized version. Once I set the test and set/get for those values it works! Thank you!

Comment: @not_a_generic_user Yeah minimized view being 1 is somewhat counter-intuitive. Happy to help.

Comment: @not_a_generic_user just out of curiosity, why didn't my code work the first time? One thing to note is that if you first open the task manager and then run the code, the task manager is unaffected, and moreover once you close it the earlier state is once again written to registry. So, try to avoid running the program while task manager is running.

Comment: This line "data[28] &= (byte)0xFE;" appears to be incorrect. I toggled it between 1 and 0 and that works. Or at least, that's how it works on Win 11

Comment: @not_a_generic_user Well, that piece toggles between 0 and 1. If something is 1 and you and it with 0xFE you should get 0. It was made specifically to ensure that the rest of the byte is not modified since other values could be stored there

Comment: My mistake then. I thought 0xFE was a value

Comment: @not_a_generic_user no problem, always happy to help